# Fourier series of complex diff eq

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

Can I just use Euler's identity to construct the Fourier Series since it is complex? I was personally thinking I could, but I wanted to be doubly sure.

Comment: What boundary conditions do you have?

Comment: So, you didn't want the Fourier Series for $y(x)$?

Comment: Would you like to have the FS solution also? If so, I am happy to provide it.

Comment: sure, is meta ok? that way i can double check and ask questions to extend my knowledge on the subject. @Dr.MV

Comment: I believe there is, but don't know how to initiate the "chat."

Comment: @Dr.MV If it is a cosine series that looks like the basel problem, i have gotten it.

Comment: It is the complex FS.  I'm finishing it in a few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those roots directly give you a homogeneous solution of $c_1 e^{(-1+i)t} + c_2 e^{(-1-i)t}$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are in general complex constants. Through judicious choice of $c_1,c_2$ using Euler's formula, this can be recast into the form $b_1 e^{-t} \cos(t) + b_2 e^{-t} \sin(t)$, so that $b_1,b_2$ can be chosen to be real (provided the initial condition is real). Which one is convenient depends on how you plan to deal with the inhomogeneity.

Comment: figured it out. thanks. just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

To find the particular solution, we expand $y(x)$ in its complex Fourier Series as

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n\,e^{inx}$$

Now, formally differentiating term by term reveals that

$$y''(x)+2y'(x)+2y(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n\,\left(-n^2+i2n+2\right)\,e^{inx}=|x|$$

Let's find the complex Fourier Series for $|x|$.  Write,

$$|x|=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} d_n\,e^{inx}$$

with

$$\begin{align}
d_n&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x|e^{-inx}dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(nx)dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1-(-1)^n}{\pi n^2}+(\pi/2) \delta_{n0}
\end{align}$$

where $\delta_{n0}$ is the Kronecker Delta and is equal to $1$ when $n=0$ and equal to $0$ otherwise.

Thus, $$c_n=-\left(\frac{1-(-1)^n}{\pi n^2}\right)\,\left(\frac{1}{-n^2+2in+2}\right)+(\pi/4) \delta_{n0}$$.

Note that the complex Fourier Series for $y(x)$ can be converted to a Fourier Series by use of Euler's identity.  Further note that the resulting series will have both cosine and sine series, and that only the odd indexed terms (other than $c_0$) are present.

Comment: thats exactly what i had./

Comment: Fantastic!  Be careful when converting to a FS.  Both cosine and sine terms are present - and only the odd indexed ones (except for $c_0$).

Comment: exactly. This is close to equivalent to the Basel equation from Euler.

Comment: Well, the FS for $|x|$ does have a $1/n^2$ term, but only the odd terms prevail.  And the series for $y$ is not really related.

Comment: fair. but i thought the basel function was the same, but exclusively sine terms.

Comment: Well, I am familiar with the Basel problem, which is to find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23165/discussion-between-forrest-channing-hunter-and-dr-mv).